# Proving $E(|X| \mid \mathscr{F})\geqslant |E(X \mid \mathscr{F})|$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

> Let $(\Omega,\mathscr{A},P)$ be a probability space and $X\in\mathscr{L}_1(\Omega,\mathscr{A},P)$ a random variable on that space. Let $\mathscr{F}\subset\mathscr{A}$ be a sigma-algebra.
>   Prove $E(|X| \mid \mathscr{F})\geqslant |E(X \mid \mathscr{F})|$, using linearity and monotonicity of the conditional expectation.

Consider $|X|=X^+ -X^-$

Then $E(|X| \mid \mathscr{F})=E(X^+ -X^- \mid \mathscr{F})=E(X^+ \mid \mathscr{F})-E(X^- \mid \mathscr{F})=?$

I do not know how to proceed. I should use monotonicity, but I do not see how.

**Question:**

How do I solve the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: More generally, if $\varphi$ is convex, then $E(\varphi(X) | \mathscr F) \ge \varphi(E(X | \mathscr F))$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Use $X \leq |X|$ and $-X \leq |X|$ to prove that $$\mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{F}) \leq \mathbb{E}(|X| \mid \mathcal{F})$$ and $$-\mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{F}) \leq \mathbb{E}(|X| \mid \mathcal{F}).$$

Comment: I am not seeing how those expressions relate to $|E(X|\mathscr{F})|$

Comment: I cannot replace them on my initial derivation since I have $X^+$ and $X^-$ inside the expected values.

Comment: @PedroGomes $|x| \leq c $ if and only if $x \leq c $ and $-x \leq c $.

Comment: @PedroGomes What I forgot to mention yesterday: It should read $$|X| = X^+ + X^-$$ in your computations (note that there is a plus on the right-hand side, not a minus)